# LEFT JOIN 11 times in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have the following data structure.

```
id| email       |  date      |  type  |  data1  |  data2 |  data3  
1 | xxx@xxx.com | 2018-11-22 |  a     |  xxx    |  xxx   |  xxx  
2 | xxx@xxx.com | 2018-11-22 |  b     |  xxx    |  xxx   |  xxx  
3 | xxx@xxx.com | 2018-11-22 |  c     |  xxx    |  xxx   |  xxx  
4 | xxx@xxx.com | 2018-11-23 |  a     |  xxx    |  xxx   |  xxx  
5 | xxx@xxx.com | 2018-11-23 |  b     |  xxx    |  xxx   |  xxx  
6 | xxx@xxx.com | 2018-11-23 |  c     |  xxx    |  xxx   |  xxx  
7 | yyy@yyy.com | 2018-11-22 |  a     |  xxx    |  xxx   |  xxx  
8 | yyy@yyy.com | 2018-11-22 |  b     |  xxx    |  xxx   |  xxx
```

I wish to create a result list as below, i.e. combine the same email, date of different type into one row.

```
email       |  date      |  a-data1  |  a-data2 |  a-data3 |  b-data1 | ....  
xxx@xxx.com | 2018-11-22 |  xxx      |  xxx     |  xxx     |  xxx     | ....
xxx@xxx.com | 2018-11-23 |  xxx      |  xxx     |  xxx     |  xxx     | ....  
yyy@yyy.com | 2018-11-22 |  xxx      |  xxx     |  xxx     |  xxx     | ....
```

I tried the following way but it loaded super long time as there are 11 types (so I left join 11 times... ) and each type has 10-30 data respectively.

```
        SELECT DISTINCT t_0.email, t_0.date, 
        t_a.data1 AS ta_data1, t_a.data2 AS ta_data2 , ... , t_k.data30 AS tk_data30 
        FROM TABLE AS t_0
        LEFT JOIN mytable AS t_a
        ON ( t_0.email = t_a.email AND t_0.date = t_a.date )
        LEFT JOIN mytable AS t_b
        ON ( t_0.email = t_b.email AND t_0.date = t_b.date )
    ...
        LEFT JOIN mytable AS t_k
        ON ( t_0.email = t_k.email AND t_0.date = t_k.date )
```

What will be a good way to generate the list efficiently?

EDITED
Solved by the following way

```
SELECT email, `date`,
GROUP_CONCAT(if(form_type = 'a', data1, NULL)) AS 'A1_a',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(form_type = 'a', data2, NULL)) AS 'A1_b',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(form_type = 'a', data3, NULL)) AS 'A2_a',
GROUP_CONCAT(if(form_type = 'a', data4, NULL)) AS 'A2_b', 
.
.
.
FROM mytable
GROUP BY email, `date`
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Comment: Consider handling data display related requirements in your application code (eg: PHP, Java, C++ etc)

Comment: A schema like this is a pretty clear violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If possible try and restructure this into a one-to-many relational structure as that will make your query almost trivial.

Comment: @tadman but sad that the schema is not possible to change at this stage

Comment: Then join a ridiculous number of times it is.